# Update records in play framework 2.5 in java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to the play framework. I have been writing basic create, find, delete and update Employee records in java using play framework 2.5. I am having problems with updating the record. This my code in Controller file, I want to replace the department of the employee id wise. I know how to extract the record but have no idea how to update it.

```
  public class EmployeeController extends Controller {
        public Result addEmployee() {
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee(100001L, "Test", "User", "HR");
            newEmployee.save();
            return ok("Employee Created!");
        }

        public Result addEmployee1() {
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee(100002L, "Test", "User2", "DEPT001");
            newEmployee.save();
            return ok(Json.toJson(newEmployee));
        }

        public Result UpdateEmployee() {
            Employee oldrecord = Employee.find.byId(100002L);
        }
}
```

Comment: How about call the method `update`? If you are using ebeans base model this method should me available to you then you can update you entity.

Comment: @pedroct92  Yeah I am using the Ebeans base model, regarding the usage of update, do we need to pass the id as parameter in UpdateEmployee method?

Comment: `oldrecord.update();` you just need to do that. Of course, As long you have your object loaded as you showed on your code. Or you can even so a stateless updated `MyModel x = new Model(); x.id= 10l; x.update();`